# NuGet packages added to my project that are not referenced

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

When restoring NuGet packages I see that Xamarin.ios.CameraViewController is restored to my package and with it, all its dependencies. But I never referenced Xamarin.ios.CameriaViewController nor it is a dependency of my referenced packages.

My csproj nuget references:

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Acr.UserDialogs">
  <Version>7.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="CarouselView.FormsPlugin">
  <Version>5.2.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView">
  <Version>2.0.11</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="GMImagePicker.Xamarin">
  <Version>2.3.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http">
  <Version>2.2.29</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <Version>12.0.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Plugin.FacebookClient">
  <Version>1.4.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Plugin.FileUploader">
  <Version>1.4.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Plugin.GoogleClient">
  <Version>1.1.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Remote.Linq.Newtonsoft.Json">
  <Version>5.8.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Rg.Plugins.Popup">
  <Version>1.1.5.188</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="SQLite.Net.Async-PCL">
  <Version>3.1.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="SQLite.Net.Core-PCL">
  <Version>3.1.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete">
  <Version>16.4.0.54</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity">
  <Version>3.2.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media">
  <Version>4.0.1.5</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle">
  <Version>3.0.0.5</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugins.Messaging">
  <Version>5.2.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials">
  <Version>1.0.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="3.4.0.1029999" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit">
  <Version>4.3.0</Version>
  <ExcludeAssets>all</ExcludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.ImagePicker">
  <Version>1.0.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn">
  <Version>4.4.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamd.Plugins.Forms.ImageCarousel">
  <Version>1.0.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xfx.Controls">
  <Version>1.1.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

So why is it referenced? how can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a dependency of `Xamarin.Forms.ImagePicker.iOS`, which is a dependency of `Xamarin.Forms.ImagePicker`.

Comment: Thanx, it turns out I didnt even need that package, I couldnt publish my app because of the Swift3 dependencies, while xCode added Swift5, there were different versions.

Answer (score 1):

- with package references being maintained in the project file, only
  top level dependencies are listed there, i.e. packages you have
  explicitly added.
- Now, packages can depend on other packages. These
  package become your transitive dependencies - Packages that you did
  not add explicitly but now you depend on them implicitly.
- Most times you don't care too much about them which is why they don't show up in
  the list of installed packages i.e. top level dependencie.
- You can however, take a look at all your dependencies inclusing transitive ones - 
  open the obj directory for your project. You'll see `projects.assetes.json` You'll see something like

  ```
  "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/6.2.8": {
   "type": "package",
   "dependencies": {
     "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "2.1.0",
     "Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler": "2.2.3",
     "Microsoft.Net.UWPCoreRuntimeSdk": "2.2.8",
     "NETStandard.Library": "2.0.3"
  }
  ```

In that example, `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` is a package that you installed explicitly and would see in your csproj references but it also brings in a bunch of its own dependecies i.e. `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms`, `Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler`, etc.